# SQL: select multiple rows with same column value based on where condtion

Tags: sql

for example:

if have table like below

```
OrderNumber  item
--------------------
1            pen
2            pencil
1            box
```

in my where condition if i put **item=pen,box** it should give **two/one** rows since order number is same for pen and box.
if i put **item=pen,pencil** result should be **empty** since order number is different. how to compose this sql query. we have record over 40 thousand. so query should be very optimistic.

Comment: Look into RowCount() and PartitionBy

Comment: What exactly do you mean by puting "item=pen,box"?

Comment: Basically if I get list of items I need to find common order number.. If not found I need to create one.. So if items selected are pen and box I already have that order..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the tag for the relevant rdbms, and what you have already tried.

Comment: @ryan with partition still I get two rows for items pen, pencil but I know with same row number.. Again I need to add programming logic to segregate right? .. What if I need to select common ordernumber from 100 items.. It can give 1000+ rows..

Comment: @Manjunath Sorry, I guess I didn't fully understand your business logic which you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed this using.

```
Select OrderNumber 
from @table 
where item IN (@item1,@item2) 
GROUP BY (OrderNumber) 
having count(distinct item) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the 'item' values, the code below returns the common OrderNumber and solves your problem:

```
select OrderNumber from @tempTable
where item in (@param1,@param2)
group by OrderNumber
having count(OrderNumber) > 1
```

Comment: Hi this did not work. for example: we have multiple rows with same OrderNumber and item. so ,count(OrderNumber ) > 1 will be true even before checking 2nd item